# Force Silverlight DataForm into Normal mode

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dataform

I'm trying to use the DataForm to display data.  The CurrentItem is bound to a property on my ViewModel.  The property it is bound to is a simple poco.  I've created a custom readonly template.  Everything works fine except I can't figure out how to make the DataForm appear "Enabled" or in the Normal state.  The data isn't editable, it's displayed as readonly.

The only way I've been able to get it to display in the Normal state was to edit the template and set the Opacity to 100% for the DisabledVisual border.

Is there a better way to do this or use the DataForm for displaying data that isn't editable but still appear enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it: jedwards14.blogspot.com/2011/02/silerlight-data-forms-with.html. I do have a busy indicator, apparently this is still and issue: silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/4729